# Story about rats in ESP experiments

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, telepathy

Possibly from *Omni* magazine in the early 80s.  A researcher of psychic phenomena is exposed as a fraud — he's been faking results showing that rats could predict the future or something.  But the end of the story reveals that the rats **are** psychic — they are influencing the researcher, causing him to reward the rats with treats (and thus causing spurious results), and the implication is that the next researcher to lead the facility will end up controlled by the rats as well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

["Controlled Experiment"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64135), a short story by [Rick Conley](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?12240), first published in [*Omni*, November 1978](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?59885+c), which can be borrowed (free but registration required) from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/sim_omni_1978-11_1_2/mode/2up).

> "I have called this press conference to announce my resignation from the American Psionic Institute."
>
> [. . .]
>
> "A few weeks ago, I implanted in the brains of rats electrodes that, when energized by a random-number generator, produce highly pleasurable sensations in the animals. My objective: to see if the rats could, through telekinesis—mind over matter—influence the generator to give more than the expected chance number of stimulations.
>
> "I reported almost immediate success—clear evidence of psychic ability! But then . . . then some of my colleagues, puzzled by the excessive attention I was paying to my apparatus, watched, concealed, as I manipulated the equipment to deliver additional stimulations to the rats."
>
> The old man sighed.
>
> "Why did I cheat? I don't know. In fact, until my colleagues confronted me with the evidence , I was barely aware of my actions.

Another researcher, Dr. Cole, continues the project:

> More! the rats' minds shouted. More! More!
>
> But the machine ignored their demands; it continued to grant the creatures brief moments in paradise according to its own mechanical caprice.
>
> Then the rats tensed. The man! The man was coming!
>
> Seconds later, Dr. Cole unlocked the door to the laboratory and entered. Walking over to the experimental apparatus, he inspected the electronic counter hopefully. He was disappointed to see that in the past hour the rats had received no stimulations beyond chance expectation.
>
> Peering into the cage at the tiny creatures, he sighed. "Do something, you deadbeats! Do something!"
>
> At that moment, the rats concentrated mightily.
>
> From their minds, at the speed of thought, sprang tendrils of mental energy. Reaching deep into the recesses of Cole's mind, the tendrils touched, probed, twisted.
>
> More! the rats' minds shouted. More! More!
>
> Unconsciously, Cole turned a dial on the random number generator. The stimulations were no longer random, they came faster and faster.
>
> Even in their heightened ecstasy the rats sensed that this man was not the same one they had . . . touched . . . earlier. But still, he was a man, not a machine, and could be manipulated.
>
> They squealed in delight.
>
> They were in control again.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at later issues - someone must have lent me an old issue in the 1980s.

Comment: You're welcome it was reprinted in a Best of Omni anthology, and in [*100 Great Fantasy Short Short Stories*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?178021) which is where I read it.

Comment: I love it how every technology in the 70s can do anything by "turning a dial" :p

Comment: It was absolutely true back then - dials were the highest tech we had!